# when loop is not working fine for this Awk script

Tags: awk, while-loop

I can't get the required output. I think this code should be updated when using the loop, but I don't know how.

Please guys need your support here.

```
BEGIN {
    split("PMP,OPTTYPE,PTD,SK,ASG,DEH,CCH,I,ASGLNUM,GGMW,MCMW,SSLO,GC2MW,MC2MW,TIF,PSTNMW,OSMSMW,GC3MW,MC3MW,GC4MW,MC4MW,MMMW,TSMSMW",array,",");
    print_array2(array) 
    }

/^PMP/   {  getline
            array[1]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,7))   #PMP
            #print_array1(array)
         }
/^OPTTYPE  PTD  SK / {    getline
            while (NF>1)
             {
               array[2]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,8)) #OPTTYPE
               array[3]=trim_blank(substr($0,10,5))#PTD
               array[4]=trim_blank(substr($0,15,10)) #SK
               array[5]=trim_blank(substr($0,26,15)) #ASG
               array[6]=trim_blank(substr($0,43,3)) #DEH
               array[7]=trim_blank(substr($0,49,4)) #CCH
               array[8]=trim_blank(substr($0,53,1)) #I
               array[9]=trim_blank(substr($0,56,10)) #ASGLNUM
               #print_array2(array)
               getline
              }
            }     
/^GGMW  MCMW  SSLO/  
                {     getline
                 array[10]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,5)) #GGMW
                 array[11]=trim_blank(substr($0,7,4)) #MCMW
                 array[12]=trim_blank(substr($0,13,4)) #SSLO
                 array[13]=trim_blank(substr($0,19,5)) #GC2MW
                 array[14]=trim_blank(substr($0,26,5)) #MCS2
                 array[15]=trim_blank(substr($0,34,3)) #TIF
                 array[16]=trim_blank(substr($0,39,7)) #PSTNMW
                 array[17]=trim_blank(substr($0,47,6)) #OSMSMW
                #print_array2(array)
                 getline
                 print_array2(array)    
             }            
                         

END{}

function print_array1(array)
{
    printf("%-5s", array[1])
    printf("\n");
}

function print_array2(array)
{
    printf("%-5s", array[1])
    printf("%-8s", array[2])
    printf("%-6s", array[3])
    printf("%-10s", array[4])
    printf("%-15s", array[5])
    printf("%-4s", array[6])
    printf("%4s ", array[7])
    printf("%-4s", array[8])
    printf("%-10s", array[9])
    #for(item=2;item<=9;item++){array[item]=""}

    printf("%-5s", array[10])
    printf("%-5s", array[11])
    printf("%-5s", array[12])
    printf("%-6s", array[13])
    printf("%-6s", array[14])
    printf("%-4s", array[15])
    printf("%-7s", array[16])
    printf("%-6s", array[17])
    printf("\n");
    #for(item=2;item<=9;item++){array[item]=""}
}
function trim_blank(str){
#trim will remove the SPACE & TAB at begining or end of str
  blk=" "
  tab="\t"
  while(1){
    if((substr(str,1,1)==blk)||(substr(str,1,1)==tab)) {str=substr(str,2,(length(str)-1))}
    else if((substr(str,length(str),1)==blk)||(substr(str,length(str),1)==tab)) {str=substr(str,1,(length(str)-1))}
    else {return str}
    }
}
```

The input is as shown:--

```
PMP
   5

OPTTYPE  PTD  SK         ASG              DEH   CCH I  ASGLNUM
PGWPW      2        9091 224477695101     0     2
MGMPW     12        9091 224477695101     0     2   Y



GGMW  MCMW  SSLO  GC2MW  MC2MW  TIF  PSTNMW  OSMSMW
0     0     0     1      1      0    0       0

GC3MW  MC3MW  GC4MW  MC4MW
0      0      0      0

MMMW  TSMSMW
0     0

END



PMP
   7

OPTTYPE  PTD  SK         ASG              DEH   CCH I  ASGLNUM
PGWPW      2        9096 224477695106     0     2
MGMPW     12        9096 224477695106     0     2   Y



GGMW  MCMW  SSLO  GC2MW  MC2MW  TIF  PSTNMW  OSMSMW
0     0     1     0      1      0    0       0

GC3MW  MC3MW  GC4MW  MC4MW
0      0      0      0

MMMW  TSMSMW
0     0

END


PMP
 300

OPTTYPE  PTD  SK         ASG              DEH   CCH I  ASGLNUM



GGMW  MCMW  SSLO  GC2MW  MC2MW  TIF  PSTNMW  OSMSMW
0     0     0     0      0      0    0       0

GC3MW  MC3MW  GC4MW  MC4MW
0      0      0      0

MMMW  TSMSMW
0     0

END

PMP
 236

OPTTYPE  PTD  SK         ASG              DEH   CCH I  ASGLNUM
MGMPW     12        8025 224477606916     0     2   Y



GGMW  MCMW  SSLO  GC2MW  MC2MW  TIF  PSTNMW  OSMSMW
0     0     1     1      1      0    0       0

GC3MW  MC3MW  GC4MW  MC4MW
0      0      0      0

MMMW  TSMSMW
0     0

END
```

The required output will be like that

The main point in the code is to check the lines after (`/^OPTTYPE  PTD  SK         ASG/`):
1)If there is no data, `NF=0` -- > The `PMP` value and other parameters will not be shown in the printout. So No printout will be shown for `PMP=300`.
2) If there is a data `NF>0`. there will be a loop to go through every line. Then print all the data. So, for `PMP=5` & `PMP=7` there will be 2 records of output. For `PMP=236`, there is only one printout.

```
PMP     OPTTYPE  PTD  SK    ASG            DEH   CCH  I  ASGLNUM   GGMW MCMW SSLO GC2MW MC2MW TIF PSTNMW OSMSMW GC3MW MC3MW GC4MW MC4MW MMMW TSMSMW
5       PGWPW    2    9091  224477695101   0     2                 0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0    
5       MGMPW    12   9091  224477695101   0     2    Y            0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0    
7       PGWPW    2    9096  224477695106   0     2                 0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0    
7       MGMPW    12   9096  224477695106   0     2    Y            0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0    
236     MGMPW    12   8025  224477606916   0     2    Y            0    0    1    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
```

Comment: Please create and post a [mcve] that is just sufficient to demonstrate your problem and doesn't contain a lot of extraneous code, input, and output. As a good rule of thumb, we shouldn't need scroll bars to be able to read your question.

Comment: Regarding your calls to `getline` - please read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline as a) you probably shouldn't be using it and b) if you are going to use it, that's not how to do so.

Comment: @markp-fuso I updated the requirements and explain more about the output requrired.     I explain why PMP=300 will not be shown in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying OP's current code:

- adjust `printf` formats to match OP's expected output
- add a two-dimensional array to store the `OPTTYPE` block data
- add code for the `GC3MW` and `MMMW` blocks
- streamline the `trim_blank()` function
- consolidate the `print_array1()` and `print_array2()` functions

One `awk` idea:

```
$ cat parse.1.awk

BEGIN      { n = split("PMP,OPTTYPE,PTD,SK,ASG,DEH,CCH,I,ASGLNUM,GGMW,MCMW,SSLO,GC2MW,MC2MW,TIF,PSTNMW,OSMSMW,GC3MW,MC3MW,GC4MW,MC4MW,MMMW,TSMSMW",array,",")
                 split("-8,-9,-5,-6,-15,-6,-5,-3,-10,-5,-5,-5,-6,-6,-4,-7,-7,-6,-6,-6,-6,-5,-6",fmt,",")
             for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
                 printf "%*s", fmt[i], array[i]
             print ""
           }

/^PMP/     { getline
             delete arr1
             delete arr2
             arr1[1]=$1                                         #PMP
           }

/^OPTTYPE/ { getline
             cnt=0
             while (NF>1) {
                   cnt++
                   arr2[cnt][2]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,8))      #OPTTYPE
                   arr2[cnt][3]=trim_blank(substr($0,10,5))     #PTD
                   arr2[cnt][4]=trim_blank(substr($0,15,10))    #SK
                   arr2[cnt][5]=trim_blank(substr($0,26,15))    #ASG
                   arr2[cnt][6]=trim_blank(substr($0,43,3))     #DEH
                   arr2[cnt][7]=trim_blank(substr($0,49,4))     #CCH
                   arr2[cnt][8]=trim_blank(substr($0,53,1))     #I
                   arr2[cnt][9]=trim_blank(substr($0,56,10))    #ASGLNUM
                   getline
             }
           }

/^GGMW/    { getline
             arr1[10]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,5))                #GGMW
             arr1[11]=trim_blank(substr($0,7,4))                #MCMW
             arr1[12]=trim_blank(substr($0,13,4))               #SSLO
             arr1[13]=trim_blank(substr($0,19,5))               #GC2MW
             arr1[14]=trim_blank(substr($0,26,5))               #MC2MW
             arr1[15]=trim_blank(substr($0,33,4))               #TIF
             arr1[16]=trim_blank(substr($0,38,7))               #PSTNMW
             arr1[17]=trim_blank(substr($0,46,7))               #OSMSMW
           }

/^GC3MW/   { getline
             arr1[18]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,6))                #GC3MW
             arr1[19]=trim_blank(substr($0,8,6))                #MC3MW
             arr1[20]=trim_blank(substr($0,15,6))               #GC4MW
             arr1[21]=trim_blank(substr($0,22,6))               #MC4MW
           }

/^MMMW/    { getline
             arr1[22]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,5))                #GC3MW
             arr1[23]=trim_blank(substr($0,7,7))                #MC3MW
           }

/^END/     { print_lines() }

function print_lines(      i,j) {
    for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) {
        printf "%*s", fmt[1], arr1[1]
        for (j=2;j<=9;j++)
            printf "%*s", fmt[j], arr2[i][j]
        for (j=10;j<=n;j++)
            printf "%*s", fmt[j], arr1[j]
        print ""
    }
}

function trim_blank(str) {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",str)
    return str
}
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `GNU awk` for two-dimensional array support (`arr2[][]`)
- while there are some downsides to using `getline` (see link in Ed Morton's comment) there aren't any issues (in this case) that keep us from generating the desired results

This generates:

```
$ awk -f parse.1.awk input.txt
PMP     OPTTYPE  PTD  SK    ASG            DEH   CCH  I  ASGLNUM   GGMW MCMW SSLO GC2MW MC2MW TIF PSTNMW OSMSMW GC3MW MC3MW GC4MW MC4MW MMMW TSMSMW
5       PGWPW    2    9091  224477695101   0     2                 0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
5       MGMPW    12   9091  224477695101   0     2    Y            0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
7       PGWPW    2    9096  224477695106   0     2                 0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
7       MGMPW    12   9096  224477695106   0     2    Y            0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
236     MGMPW    12   8025  224477606916   0     2    Y            0    0    1    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
```

---

An alternative approach:

- replace the one-dimensional array `arr1[]` with 4x variables (`col_1`, `col_10_17`, `col_18_21` and `col_22_23`)
- replace the two-dimensional array `arr2[][]` with a one-dimensional array `arr[]` (eliminates need for `GNU awk`)
- replace `printf` calls with comparable `sprintf()` calls
- eliminate the `getline` calls

One `awk` idea:

```
$ cat parse.2.awk

BEGIN      { n = split("PMP,OPTTYPE,PTD,SK,ASG,DEH,CCH,I,ASGLNUM,GGMW,MCMW,SSLO,GC2MW,MC2MW,TIF,PSTNMW,OSMSMW,GC3MW,MC3MW,GC4MW,MC4MW,MMMW,TSMSMW",array,",")
                 split("-8,-9,-5,-6,-15,-6,-5,-3,-10,-5,-5,-5,-6,-6,-4,-7,-7,-6,-6,-6,-6,-5,-6",fmt,",")
             for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
                 printf "%*s", fmt[i], array[i]
             print ""
           }

NF==0      { blk = ""        }

/^PMP/     { blk = "PMP"
             cnt = 0
             delete arr
             next
           }
/^OPTTYPE/ { blk = "OPTTYPE" ; next }
/^GGMW/    { blk = "GGMW"    ; next }
/^GC3MW/   { blk = "GC3MW"   ; next }
/^MMMW/    { blk = "MMMW"    ; next }
/^END/     { blk = "END"            }

blk        {      if (blk == "PMP")
                     col_1 =      sprintf( "%*s", fmt[1], $1 )

             else if (blk == "OPTTYPE")
                     arr[++cnt] = sprintf( "%*s", fmt[2], trim_blank(substr($0, 1, 8)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[3], trim_blank(substr($0,10, 5)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[4], trim_blank(substr($0,15,10)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[5], trim_blank(substr($0,26,15)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[6], trim_blank(substr($0,43, 3)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[7], trim_blank(substr($0,49, 4)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[8], trim_blank(substr($0,53, 1)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[9], trim_blank(substr($0,56,10)) )

             else if (blk == "GGMW")
                     col_10_17 =  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[10], trim_blank(substr($0, 1,5)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[11], trim_blank(substr($0, 7,4)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[12], trim_blank(substr($0,13,4)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[13], trim_blank(substr($0,19,5)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[14], trim_blank(substr($0,26,5)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[15], trim_blank(substr($0,33,4)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[16], trim_blank(substr($0,38,7)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[17], trim_blank(substr($0,46,7)) )

             else if (blk == "GC3MW")
                     col_18_21 =  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[18], trim_blank(substr($0, 1,6)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[19], trim_blank(substr($0, 8,6)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[20], trim_blank(substr($0,15,6)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[21], trim_blank(substr($0,22,6)) )

             else if (blk == "MMMW")
                     col_22_23 =  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[22], trim_blank(substr($0, 1,5)) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[23], trim_blank(substr($0, 7,7)) )

             else if (blk == "END")
                     print_lines()
           }

function print_lines(      i,j) {
    for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) {
        print col_1 arr[i] col_10_17 col_18_21 col_22_23
    }
}

function trim_blank(str) {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",str)
    return str
}
```

This generates:

```
$ awk -f parse.2.awk input.txt
PMP     OPTTYPE  PTD  SK    ASG            DEH   CCH  I  ASGLNUM   GGMW MCMW SSLO GC2MW MC2MW TIF PSTNMW OSMSMW GC3MW MC3MW GC4MW MC4MW MMMW TSMSMW
5       PGWPW    2    9091  224477695101   0     2                 0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
5       MGMPW    12   9091  224477695101   0     2    Y            0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
7       PGWPW    2    9096  224477695106   0     2                 0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
7       MGMPW    12   9096  224477695106   0     2    Y            0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
236     MGMPW    12   8025  224477606916   0     2    Y            0    0    1    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
```

---

Yet another alternative:

- replace the `substr()` calls by parsing based on fixed width fields

One `awk` idea:

```
$ cat parse.3.awk

BEGIN      { n = split("PMP,OPTTYPE,PTD,SK,ASG,DEH,CCH,I,ASGLNUM,GGMW,MCMW,SSLO,GC2MW,MC2MW,TIF,PSTNMW,OSMSMW,GC3MW,MC3MW,GC4MW,MC4MW,MMMW,TSMSMW",array,",")
                 split("-8,-9,-5,-6,-15,-6,-5,-3,-10,-5,-5,-5,-6,-6,-4,-7,-7,-6,-6,-6,-6,-5,-6",fmt,",")
             for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
                 printf "%*s", fmt[i], array[i]
             print ""
           }

NF==0      { blk = "" }

/^PMP/     { cnt = 0
             delete arr
             blk = "PMP"     ; FIELDWIDTHS = "20"                ; next
           }
/^OPTTYPE/ { blk = "OPTTYPE" ; FIELDWIDTHS = "9 5 11 16 6 4 3 10"; next }
/^GGMW/    { blk = "GGMW"    ; FIELDWIDTHS = "6 6  6  7 7 5 8  7"; next }
/^GC3MW/   { blk = "GC3MW"   ; FIELDWIDTHS = "7 7  7  6"         ; next }
/^MMMW/    { blk = "MMMW"    ; FIELDWIDTHS = "6 7"               ; next }
/^END/     { blk = "END"     ; FIELDWIDTHS = ""                         }

blk        {      if (blk == "PMP")
                     col_1 =      sprintf( "%*s", fmt[1], trim_blank($1) )

             else if (blk == "OPTTYPE")
                     arr[++cnt] = sprintf( "%*s", fmt[2], trim_blank($1) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[3], trim_blank($2) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[4], trim_blank($3) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[5], trim_blank($4) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[6], trim_blank($5) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[7], trim_blank($6) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[8], trim_blank($7) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[9], trim_blank($8) )

             else if (blk == "GGMW")
                     col_10_17 =  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[10], trim_blank($1) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[11], trim_blank($2) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[12], trim_blank($3) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[13], trim_blank($4) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[14], trim_blank($5) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[15], trim_blank($6) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[16], trim_blank($7) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[17], trim_blank($8) )

             else if (blk == "GC3MW")
                     col_18_21 =  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[18], trim_blank($1) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[19], trim_blank($2) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[20], trim_blank($3) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[21], trim_blank($4) )

             else if (blk == "MMMW")
                     col_22_23 =  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[22], trim_blank($1) ) \
                                  sprintf( "%*s", fmt[23], trim_blank($2) )

             else if (blk == "END")
                     print_lines()
           }

function print_lines(      i,j) {
    for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) {
        print col_1 arr[i] col_10_17 col_18_21 col_22_23
    }
}

function trim_blank(str) {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",str)
    return str
}
```

**NOTE:** requires `GNU awk` for `FIELDWIDTHS` support

This generates:

```
$ awk -f parse.2.awk input.txt
PMP     OPTTYPE  PTD  SK    ASG            DEH   CCH  I  ASGLNUM   GGMW MCMW SSLO GC2MW MC2MW TIF PSTNMW OSMSMW GC3MW MC3MW GC4MW MC4MW MMMW TSMSMW
5       PGWPW    2    9091  224477695101   0     2                 0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
5       MGMPW    12   9091  224477695101   0     2    Y            0    0    0    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
7       PGWPW    2    9096  224477695106   0     2                 0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
7       MGMPW    12   9096  224477695106   0     2    Y            0    0    1    0     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
236     MGMPW    12   8025  224477606916   0     2    Y            0    0    1    1     1     0   0      0      0     0     0     0     0    0
```